# How to migrate ActiveModel with STI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My system previously already had Product model there with many existed records, but now I want to have a BaseProduct as a fundamental ActiveRecord::Base(move some common used attributes in) and make Product and (Future)Product can extend it.

Question: How can I migrate those old records? what I can think of are below:

- rails g model BaseProduct.
- Create Product and (Future)Product class with STI support.
- rake task to move all old product table records to new BaseProduct.
- Remove old Product table.

Any else missing?

Comment: more details pleas

Comment: added more detail thoughts of what I plan to do

Comment: I will say instead of removing old table rename it so you won;t need to move all records

Comment: STI is a way of managing diverging domains with that use the same data.  So ideally you would be not need to change the table.  Do you really need STI here? We are using it for splitting out different kinds of exports where I am. The things to do for the files are quite different but all of the data is the same. If this is not the case for you then maybe you don't need STI.

Comment: @unflores yes basically the fields will be the same, I just want to use inheritance to control the different price of different products, etc. but since Product already extends from ActiveRecord::Base, how can I not touching the db and provide another BaseProduct to it?

Comment: @DeepakMahakale yes that will be good, so I can rename the table to BaseProduct and put STI type="Product". is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change your table just reference the original table from your inherited class:

```
class BaseProduct < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "products"
end

class Product < BaseProduct
end

class FutureProduct < BaseProduct
end
```